# android. run two events with an action

Tags: android, events, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I have a RelativeLayout in FragmentActivity that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
...
<com.my.android.Myview
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </RelativeLayout>
</com.my.android.Myview>
```

I have a OnTouchListener in com.my.android.Myview.

And OnClickListener for RelativeLayout in FragmentActivity .

The problem is that I can not call the two events.
I managed to call one if not the other. But not the two events

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure if what you are trying is a good idea. 
Anyways, you can  try something like this:

```
    OnClickListener parent= new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         //whatever
        }
    }


    OnClickListener child= new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
         parent.onClick(null);

         //whatever else
        }
    }

    parentView.setOnClickListener(parent);
    childView.setOnClickListener(child);
```